# undefined columns selected: hlme

Tags: r

I ran the following code using 'hlme' and keep getting the following error message:

```
m1a <- hlme(GFR_QRT_MEAN ~ poly(TIME_QRT, degree = 3, raw = F),random = ~ 1, subject = "ID",data = WK, ng = 1)

"Error in [.data.frame(x, i, j) : undefined columns selected".
```

I checked the dataset '`WK`', "`GFR_QRT_MEAN`" ,"`TIME_QRT`" , and "`ID`" are all in the dataset. I also tried this dataset to do other regression analysis using these three variables. There was no such error message at all. Could you kindly help me to find the reason? Thank you!

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty strange. As you might know, `poly` function's default for `raw` is `FALSE`. For `iris` data, I can reproduce similar(or same) error by

```
iris2 <- iris %>%
  mutate(Species = as.numeric(Species))
hlme(Sepal.Length ~ poly(iris2$Sepal.Width, degree = 3, raw = F), random = ~ 1, subject = "Species", data = iris2, ng = 1)
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , v) : undefined columns selected
```

There were several strange way to fix this is,

1. `hlme(Sepal.Length ~ poly(iris2$Sepal.Width, degree = 3), random = ~ 1, subject = "Species", data = iris2, ng = 1)`
2. `hlme(Sepal.Length ~ poly(iris2$Sepal.Width, degree = 3, raw = FALSE), random = ~ 1, subject = "Species", data = iris2, ng = 1)`

what's weird is

```
x <- poly(iris2$Sepal.Width, degree = 3, raw = FALSE)
y <- poly(iris2$Sepal.Width, degree = 3, raw = F)
z <- poly(iris2$Sepal.Width, degree = 3)
head(x)
                1            2            3
[1,]  0.083201357 -0.016039377 -0.086836597
[2,] -0.010776079 -0.053252127  0.029150387
[3,]  0.026814895 -0.056361540 -0.023300097
[4,]  0.008019408 -0.057805919  0.003760092
[5,]  0.101996844  0.009397687 -0.092912930
[6,]  0.158383306  0.121697905 -0.027105624

head(y)
                1            2            3
[1,]  0.083201357 -0.016039377 -0.086836597
[2,] -0.010776079 -0.053252127  0.029150387
[3,]  0.026814895 -0.056361540 -0.023300097
[4,]  0.008019408 -0.057805919  0.003760092
[5,]  0.101996844  0.009397687 -0.092912930
[6,]  0.158383306  0.121697905 -0.027105624

head(z)
                1            2            3
[1,]  0.083201357 -0.016039377 -0.086836597
[2,] -0.010776079 -0.053252127  0.029150387
[3,]  0.026814895 -0.056361540 -0.023300097
[4,]  0.008019408 -0.057805919  0.003760092
[5,]  0.101996844  0.009397687 -0.092912930
[6,]  0.158383306  0.121697905 -0.027105624
```

In conclusion, instead of `raw = F`, try nothing or `raw = FALSE`